# CakePHP count query gives different result when run in phpmyadmin

Tags: cakephp

I am running the following query on my database:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, `Doctor`.`device_type` FROM `doctors` AS `Doctor` WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Doctor`.`device_type`
```

and it gives the result:-

```
count  device_type
47     Android
23     iPhone
```

Whereas when running this query as a CakePHP query it gives the result as '2':-

```
$this->Doctor->find('count',array('group'=>'Doctor.device_type'));
```

Can anyone please suggest why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CakePHP result is correct as it is returning a count of the number of results returned by your query. In your case you have 2 rows: 'Android' and 'iPhone'.

`find('count')` always returns an integer, not an array. What Cake is doing is basically this:-

```
$data = $this->Doctor->find('all', array('group' => 'Doctor.device_type'));
$count = count($data); // This is what find('count') will return.
```

You need to do something like the following instead:-

```
$data = $this->Doctor->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Doctor.device_type',
        'COUNT(Doctor.*) AS count'
    )
    'group' => 'Doctor.device_type'
));
```

Comment: @shweta great! Please accept this as the correct answer to help others with a similar problem. :-)

Comment: I am not getting any option for this

Comment: There should be a grey tick to the left of the answer (below the points counter). Accepting correct answers will improve your reputation on Stack Overflow so it's worth doing when you receive a valid answer to a question.